# how to save printer name configuration in appSettings from PrinterSettings looping in combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, configuration, app-config

I'm trying to save printer name configuration in appSettings from PrinterSettings looping in combobox in vb.net

but there is an error  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

in this line code `_GeneralSettings.name_printer = cmbPrinter.Text`

maybe you are wrong in my code

and if there is something simple in the implementation of the code below please guide me

Thanks

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Private _GeneralSettings As GeneralSettings = Nothing
    Private Sub SaveLocalSettings()
        Dim appConfigFile = String.Format("{0}\howtoSavePrinternameconfig.exe.config", Utils.GetAppPath())
        _GeneralSettings.name_printer = cmbPrinter.Text
        Dim TypesofPrinters = PrinterType.InkJet
        If rdoJenisPrinterDotMatrix.Checked Then
            TypesofPrinters = PrinterType.DotMatrix
        ElseIf rdoJenisPrinterMiniPOS.Checked Then
            TypesofPrinters = PrinterType.MiniPOS
        End If
        _GeneralSettings.Printer_Type = TypesofPrinters
        ' save info printer
        AppConfigHelper.SaveValue("printerName", _GeneralSettings.name_printer, appConfigFile)
        AppConfigHelper.SaveValue("PrinterType", Convert.ToString(CInt(Math.Truncate(TypesofPrinters))), appConfigFile)

    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadPrinter()
        For Each printer In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
            cmbPrinter.Items.Add(printer)
        Next printer
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadPrinter()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnsave.Click
        SaveLocalSettings()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Enum PrinterType
    InkJet = 1
    DotMatrix = 2
    MiniPOS = 3
End Enum
Public Class GeneralSettings
    Public Property name_printer As String
    Public Property Printer_Type As PrinterType
End Class
Public Module Utils
    Public Function GetAppPath() As String
        Return Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    End Function
End Module
Public Module AppConfigHelper
    Private Const SECTION_NAME As String = "appSettings"
    Private Function IsSectionExist(ByVal sectionName As String, ByVal appSetting As AppSettingsSection) As Boolean
        Dim keyCount = appSetting.Settings.AllKeys.Where(Function(key) key = sectionName).Count()
        Return keyCount > 0
    End Function
    Public Sub SaveValue(ByVal sectionName As String, ByVal value As String, ByVal appConfigFile As String)
        Dim configFileMap = New ExeConfigurationFileMap()
        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = appConfigFile

        Dim configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        Dim section = CType(configuration.GetSection(SECTION_NAME), AppSettingsSection)

        Try
            If IsSectionExist(sectionName, section) Then
                section.Settings(sectionName).Value = value
            Else
                section.Settings.Add(sectionName, value)
            End If
            configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, False)
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(SECTION_NAME)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```